# Rsync don't create directory at target if if doesn't exist

Tags: linux, rsync

I have set rsync to backup the root filesystem on a Raspberry Pi to an USB drive every day using `/usr/bin/rsync -ahPHAXx --stats --delete-during / /mnt/backup/pi-backup/`. However, if the USB disk isn't mounted, rsync creates the `/pi-backup` directory inside `/mnt/backup`. I don't want that to happen and want rsync to fail with an error if `/mnt/backup/pi-backup` didn't already exist. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the directory exists with Bash and then run rsync command.

```
# Example test one-liner
# If backup directory exists, print exists, else print error.
if [ -d "/mnt/backup/pi-backup" ] ; then echo "exists" ; else echo "Error: backup directory doesn't exist!"; fi

# One-liner with rsync command
# I didn't test this with the rsync command. 
if [ -d "/mnt/backup/pi-backup" ] ; then /usr/bin/rsync -ahPHAXx --stats --delete-during / /mnt/backup/pi-backup/ ; else echo "Error: backup directory doesn't exist!"; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using this one-liner `/bin/mountpoint /mnt/backup && /usr/bin/rsync -ahPHAXx --stats --delete-during / /mnt/backup/pi-backup/`
If the USB drive isn't mounted the code with echo "/mnt/backup is not a mountpoint" and fail with exit code 1. I also made the mountpoint immutable using `sudo chattr +i /mnt/backup` with the drive unmounted so nothing can write to it if the USB is not mounted.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be achieved by appending `/.` to the target directory – at least that worked for me. So you could try something like this:

`/usr/bin/rsync -ahPHAXx --stats --delete-during / /mnt/backup/pi-backup/.`

(Kudos to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/479441/run-rsync-only-if-target-directory-exists#comment876718_479441 for this suggestion!)